# TFS - What is the best branching strategy for this scenario?

Tags: tfs, branching-and-merging, branching-strategy

My goal is to have a structure like this:

```
Project X
-- Main
-- QA
-- Dev
  -- Feature X
```

Ideally, when working on a new feature, I would like to branch off the "Main" trunk and create a new "Dev/Feature X" branch. Once I have the feature ready for testing, I would like to move the "Feature X" to "QA" with the merging tool. Then go from the "QA" branch once it is done and tested. Once that is true, I would like to merge from "QA" into "Main".

Is this possible? Id like to do this without doing a baseless merge. I am unsure how to structure the branches to achieve this solution.

Comment: See this for possible info: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5395867/how-can-i-branch-my-code-in-a-way-that-makes-testing-possible-without-contaminat?rq=1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, this is possible.

You'd branch `Main` to `QA`, then branch `QA` to `Feature X`, `Feature Y`, etc.

Then, devs code in the `Feature` branches, and when the feature is complete, merge the code from the feature branch to the `QA` branch. It's important to also have devs periodically reverse-integrate from `QA` back up to their feature branches, to make sure that all of the latest changes are present and working in their dev branch.

When the release is done and tested in the QA branch, you merge it back to `Main`, and then (if you desire) branch `Main` to a `Release` branch.

In this scenario, `Main` should always represent absolutely vetted, shippable code -- either the code you *just* shipped, or the code you're *about* to ship. No one should *ever* modify `Main` without it going through (at the very least) the `QA` branch.

Basically, the part you're missing is that your code should always travel through the `QA` branch. I usually call this an "Integration" branch instead of "QA", but the purpose is the same.

The ALM Rangers have an [awesome branching/merging guide](http://vsarbranchingguide.codeplex.com/) -- I strongly recommend reading it!

Comment: Sure. I get that and I do know that will work. I also think we will go that route but what I asked was if it would be possible to do all that except have the Dev's branch from Main to Feature X (not QA to Feature X). Im guessing that won't work since QA wont be the "parent" to the Feature so TFS won't let them later merge Feature X into QA. Is that correct?

Comment: That's correct -- it would be a baseless merge. The recommended approach is the one I talked about.